# Surprise 51 appearing in my output about a .join() function

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am doing some work for school, and trying to work with strings, lists etc.
I was asked to separate my string with a "-", every 3 letters.

By trying to do so, with the function .join(), I have my string that is separated by "51-" instead.
I have no the slightest idea of where does that 51 is coming from, as I started a fresh VSC session and there is no number in my string.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

```
# A function needed for assuming that my string is DNA
def verif_adn(chaine):
    bases_azotees = set("ACTG")
    seq_adn = False
    if chaine in bases_azotees:
        seq_adn = True
    if seq_adn:
        print("Cette chaine n'est pas une sequence ADN !\nVeuillez recommencer la saisie !")
    else:
        print(f"Sequence ADN : {chaine}")
    return chaine


# The function that gives me the issue
def affich_codon(chaine):
    chaine = verif_adn(chaine)
    for codon in range(0, len(chaine), 3):
        chaine2 = (f"{codon}-").join(chaine)
    print(f"wow : {chaine2}")
    return chaine2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chaine = "CCTAGATTTAGCGCGAGCAGCTCCATCCAATTCCTAGATTTAGCGCGAGCAGCC"
    chaine2 = ""
    affich_codon(chaine)
```

The output i get:
[image: The output i get]

I've tried to rewrite the for-loop with differents syntaxes and all of that, but because I don't understand fully the .join() function, I am unable to get around the 51 problem.
Also, I know that it can be done in different ways, but I am trying to work with .join() for this exercise.
Thank you !

Comment: `f"{codon}-"` is where your 51 comes from. That is value of `codon` at the end of a loop.

Comment: The for loop is useless. You are only keeping last value that was assigned to `chaine2`

Comment: your code that verifies if its adn is wrong. you are doing `chaine in bases_azotees`  which translates as `"CCTAGATTTAGCGCGAGCAGCTCCATCCA..." in set("ACTG")`. Instead you should check that chaine only contains the 4 characters "ACTG".  Start from scratch, implement a function and run it with several test cases. Once you have a function working move to the next one. Use a debugger to execute the code line by line and compare each step with the expected results

Comment: I'd suggest to print the value of `chaine2` inside the `for` loop, so you'll see what values it assumes during the iterations and understand how your loop works. And, for the tests, you may well use some shorter string, say 9–letters long...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a more *pythonic* way of doing that would be splitting the input string into 3-grams first, then joining the obtained list with a predefined `"-"` separator.

For the first part you may see

- [Split string every nth character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)
- [Python split string every n character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712582/python-split-string-every-n-character)
- [more...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+split+string+every+n+characters)

Comment: The second link there isn't quite the same: that's about turning `"ABCDEF"` into `["ABC", "BCD", "CDE", "DEF"]` rather than `["ABC", "DEF"]`

Comment: @slothrop Yes, but I think that's not very hard to adjust for specific needs of Delemme (OP), and studying different solutions of similar problems leads to deeper understandig and more flexibility in silving problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily split the string into groups of N characters with a generator. You can then *join()* the result of that grouping to produce the required output.

```
chaine = "CCTAGATTTAGCGCGAGCAGCTCCATCCAATTCCTAGATTTAGCGCGAGCAGCC"
N = 3
print("-".join(chaine[i:i+N] for i in range(0, len(chaine), N)))
```

**Output:**

```
CCT-AGA-TTT-AGC-GCG-AGC-AGC-TCC-ATC-CAA-TTC-CTA-GAT-TTA-GCG-CGA-GCA-GCC
```